# Laravel. Tests clear the active DB

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

The tables in my active DB are empty after tests.

I have the test environment variable `DB_CONNECTION=mysql_testing`. When I run my tests and do `dd(env('DB_CONNECTION'))` - everything is fine. I see 'mysql_testing'.

But when I write `dd( \DB::connection()->getDatabaseName())` I see the wrong DB name(for example 'db_name', but it should be 'testing_db_name') . It is the name of the active DB. It's not the config cache. Everything is fine there. I see the correct database name for the 'mysql_testing' connection. I even tried to set the test environment variable `DB_DATABASE=testing_db_name`.

Stack: Laravel 7.28.3, PHPUnit 8.5.8

Comment: Try running `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: @p-k-tharindu No. I wrote about the cache. Everything is fine there. I did `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: Show how you have defined your connections in your database config

Comment: @P.K.Tharindu
```'mysql_testing' => [ 'driver' => 'mysql', 'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_TESTING', 'testing'), ...],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching the stack trace for a long time, I found the problem! All the same, the cache turned out to be.
The config cache needs to be cleared ('php artisan config: clear') because Laravel stores the old connection name.

I just tried to clear the cache ("php artisan cache: clear") or clear and cache the configuration at the same time ("php artisan config: cache"). This is why it didn't work.

By the way, there was a problem on [GitHub](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13374) about this. But I couldn't find it because I didn't know what the problem was. There is a little life hack to avoid clearing the config cache every time before running tests if you cache your config and routes.

Thanks @P.K.Tharindu for the help. You were close to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per how you have setup your database connections, you should be defining `DB_DATABASE_TESTING=testing_db_name` not `DB_DATABASE=testing_db_name`.

Comment: It does not matter. I don't have an environment variable with that name (DB_DATABASE_TESTING). Therefore, Laravel must choose the default in the configuration.
At least I just tried to set this variable. As expected, it didn't work.